# Showing border when clicking icon on phones browser

Tags: android, html, css

I have an icon that you can interact with, basically you click on it and it toggles an visibility class.

The problem is when i click/touch it on my phone you can see like a blue marker on top of it. the function etc works, you just get that blue square in the middle of the process, which doesn't look very professionell. See image below, icon in upper corner, in the middle of the process of it being clicked.

[image]

It doesn't happen in any of my computers browsers.

And the code looks like this. CSS:

```
width: 22px;
height: 21px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 14px;
cursor: pointer;
```

HTML:

```
<img src="assets/images/heart_empty_icon.png" id="unlike" ng-click="changeLikeIcon()" />
```

I have added the element to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/6785/
and tried it on my phone from there, but same result.

Anyone know why this happens and how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#unlike {
  width: 22px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; 
}
```

Comment: Just tried user-select: none; but it doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately. I'm testing this with the latest chrome version on my phone.

Comment: Add this `#unlike:focus {
    outline: 0;
}`

Comment: Added that aswell, but still the same problem :/

Comment: Can you post link of your website ?

Comment: Thank for trying to help me out Nenad. I've set up a jsfiddle with the same element. Tried it from jsfiddle on my phone and im getting the same blue square. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/6785/

Comment: I updated my answer so try that. Remove all previous code i wrote and just add this.

Comment: Nice, that seems to do it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

#### User selection

I think that what happen is the user select the images like you would select text in a desktop browser. Adding `user-select: none;` to your css with the proper prefixes should work.

#### You can take a look at these links for more informations

[CSS Tricks articles](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Comment: Just tried user-select: none; but it doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately. I'm testing this with the latest chrome version on my phone.

Comment: Yeah, I used all of them :/

Comment: If you could update your question with a link to a page where we can see the problem it would help :)

Comment: added it to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/6785/ .. ill update the post aswell